# Intellij Custom XML Tag Formatting

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, format, coding-style, vxml

I'm currently trying to get Intellij to auto-format the way that my work wants certain tags displayed. I like Intellij's default XML formatting for the most part - minus one exception. For example, when auto-formatting some VXML code it displays things nice and nested such as:

```
<if cond="true">
    <script>function();</script>
    <assign name="example"
            expr="examplexpr" />
</if>
```

Everything lines up nice and nested. Although, I don't want the `<log>` tags to be nested. I would like for them to be one straight line. For example, this is how they look after auto-formatting:

```
<log><value expr="applicationName"/>:<value expr="currentPage"/>: RecordStart output: eduid=
    <value expr="eduid"/>
</log>
```

I want Intellij to auto-format ONLY the `<log>` tags to be a one-liner, like so:

```
<log><value expr="applicationName"/>:<value expr="currentPage"/>: RecordStart output: eduid=<value expr="eduid"/></log>
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this functionality because I don't think that you can customize formatting for only certain tags, correct?

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145809.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your  statement while writing VXML code as below:

```
<log expr="applicationName + ' : ' + currentPage +' : RecordStart output: eduid='+ eduid"/>
```

Check this! hope It will solve your problem of printing log in one single line.

Comment: Thank you! This is a much cleaner solution than what we were previously doing.